# Why is pure white output gray?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I'm trying to sequence frames into video, and I noticed all of my output is a bit darker than it should be. So I set up a pure white render through the compositor, and that's gray too.

**compositor setup (through testing, "Use Alpha" and the Alpha slider do not impact the result)**

[image]

**compositor is enabled**

[image]

**nodes are active in the compositor**

[image]

and this is what I get, a gray render

[image]

I don't have film transparency enabled. This seems super odd

EDIT: it does appear that the output is white, w/ values of R:1 G:1 B:1, but clearly it is gray

Comment: What are your color management settings (*Properties > Render*)?

Comment: filmic, I changed it to standard and It's working perfectly