# Why is this white emission object rendering as grey?

Tags: rendering, shaders, color

I am making a very simple animation - a thin torus that spins.
I want the object to be sharp and pure white.

This is my material, it has an **Emission** shader with a 1 value which is supposed to render as white pixels:

[image]

But as we can see in the **Preview**, the object renders as grey.
The Hex value in **Blender** says "FFFFFF" but the eyedropper from **ColorSlurp** says otherwise:

[image]

**Why is this object not pure white?**

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154688/why-is-pure-white-output-gray https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78284/white-background-with-filmic-blender

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find this question either when I looked :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color is "off" because the default *View Transform* for Blender is *Filmic* (Good for HDR, but can be less "accurate")- Go into Color Management (Under Render Properties), and change your *View Transform* to *Standard*:

[image: Col]

Comment: I'm sorry if you think the question is redundant, but I searched for a similar question for a good 10 minutes... this was never the way Blender used to work. "White background with filmic blender" is a question title *no one* will ever type when having this issue 

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's really upsetting that they made a standard something that changes the color set by the user...

Comment: The purpose is to better support HDR renders, but the color data gets scaled into a much wider range, thus making it "inaccurate" to what it's "supposed" to be.

Comment: I am sure there is a "purpose" however maybe this setting could have been activated when there is a need for it, or not be a default. I've never rendered a HDR scene or needed this feature in 7 years of using Blender. Oh well... now I know. Until I forget and ask again 